# dynamic binding with generic type

Tags: java, generics, dynamic-binding

i need to bind dynamic a parametic type (List) but i dont get it right...
here is an overview of my classes:

```
public abstract interface SettingsField<A> extends Window
```

then i have some classes which implements SettingsField:

```
public class StringSettingsField implements SettingsField<String>
public class MapSettingsField<K, V> implements SettingsField<Map<K, V>>
```

the first is real simple,  but eg the second is a little bit tricky... so i want to make a factory which returns SettingsFileds. I want to use dynamic binding to get the right SettingsWindow for each Object i want to put in there.
so i overload a method getField the following.
for String its quite easy:

```
public SettingsField<String> getField(String x){
    return new StringSettingsField();
}
```

but for map i have some trouble...

```
public SettingsField<Map<? extends String, ?>> getField(Map<? extends String, ?> x){
    return new MapSettingsField();
}
```

that the key is always a string is an exampe (could be ? also)
but now the compiler gives me the waring that

> MapSettingsField is a raw type. References to generic type MapSettingsField should be parameterized

but how i can do this here? the problem is just use Map is not valid, because of some problem with f-generic in java (List is not implicit subtype of List even if B is subtype of A)

any hints? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUYC, you need

```
return new MapSettingsField<? extends String, ?>();
```

Btw., `extends String` doesn't make much sense as String is final.

However, I'd go for something like

```
public <K, V> SettingsField<Map<K, V>> getField(Map<K, V> x){
    return new MapSettingsField<K, V>();
}
```

You could declare K as bounded, too, e.g.

```
public <K extends Number, V extends List> ...
```

or whatever.

Comment: First example gives you compile time error because of incorrect number of arguments for type MapSettingsField<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Map<? extends String,?>>

Comment: i think your second solutions seems to be the best because i have static type safty! thanks!